# uwsgi + django slow respawn/reload/restart

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I use django 1.7.7 and uswgi 2.0.7 on debian jessie

Uwsgi is very slow to respawn/reload/restart. It seems to reach a timeout ( 30s ).

```
Fri Jul 31 08:20:59 2015 - SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...  
Fri Jul 31 10:21:29 2015 - *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.7-debian (64bit) on [Fri Jul 31 10:21:29 2015] ***

Fri Jul 31 09:25:53 2015 - SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...  
Fri Jul 31 11:26:24 2015 - *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.7-debian (64bit) on [Fri Jul 31 11:26:24 2015] ***
```

I have the problem with two version of the uwsgi ini file. First [like describe ( django doc )](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/) :

```
 # Django's wsgi file
 module          = ntbserver.wsgi:application
```

and seconde [like describe here ( uwsgi doc )](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)

```
# Django's wsgi file
module          = ntbserver.wsgi
```

I found a third version in turorials. If i do that :

```
# Django's wsgi file
module          = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
```

It's instantaneous

```
Fri Jul 31 11:25:46 2015 - SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...  
Fri Jul 31 11:25:47 2015 - worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
Fri Jul 31 11:25:47 2015 - worker 2 buried after 1 seconds
Fri Jul 31 11:25:47 2015 - worker 3 buried after 1 seconds
Fri Jul 31 11:25:47 2015 - worker 4 buried after 1 seconds
Fri Jul 31 11:25:47 2015 - worker 5 buried after 1 seconds
Fri Jul 31 11:25:47 2015 - worker 6 buried after 1 seconds
Fri Jul 31 11:25:47 2015 - worker 7 buried after 1 seconds
Fri Jul 31 11:25:47 2015 - worker 8 buried after 1 seconds
Fri Jul 31 11:25:47 2015 - worker 9 buried after 1 seconds
Fri Jul 31 11:25:47 2015 - worker 10 buried after 1 seconds
Fri Jul 31 11:25:47 2015 - goodbye to uWSGI.
Fri Jul 31 11:25:47 2015 - VACUUM: pidfile removed.
Fri Jul 31 11:25:47 2015 - VACUUM WARNING: unix socket /run/uwsgi/app/ntbserver/socket changed inode. Skip removal
Fri Jul 31 11:25:48 2015 - *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.7-debian (64bit) on [Fri Jul 31 11:25:48 2015] ***
```

But, i don't understand the difference and the impact of this change. I can't find documentation or recommandation about that. If someone can help me.

Comment: I just noticed that if I use "django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()"; I have no more [log](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/).

Comment: If i enable the uwsgi's options "lazy-apps", it works better, but i don't know exactly why.

Comment: Still figuring this out myself, but there is some explanation to the "lazy" concepts here: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html#dealing-with-ultra-lazy-apps-like-django